# Visualizar un polígono o un punto almacenado en un mapa personalizado

Tags: google-maps, api

Tengo mapas personalizados (en My Maps) donde tengo almacenada información geográfica: puntos y polígonos. Me gustaría saber si es posible, mediante la API, mostrar al usuario un mapa con un determinado polígono o posición de los que están almacenados en mis mapas personalizados. Y si puedo modificar el color por ejemplo del polígono para diferenciarlo del resto.

Ya sé que lo puedo hacer utilizando, por ejemplo, los datos almacenados en una BBDD mediante código, pero me preguntaba si es posible referenciar los objetos almacenados en uno de mis mapas. Ya que están, para que voy a almacenarlos también en una BBDD. Espero haberlo explicado bien.

Gracias.